# Para que sirve set_at()

Tags: python, pygame

Aun no puedo entender para que sirve el método set_at de las mascaras en Python intente con muchas pruebas en bucles, sin bucle y nada no noto cambios en la mascara

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
pygame.display.set_caption('Máscara')
screen.fill((255,255,255))
mask_image = pygame.image.load('ship.png').convert_alpha()
mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(mask_image)

mask_points = mask.outline()
print(mask_points)

for point in mask_points:
mask.set_at(point, 0)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,(0,0,0), (point[0], point[1], 5,5))

print(mask_points)
```

imprimo sus puntos para ver si existe algun cambio pero llego a notar nada

Comment: Tu pregunta contiene, en realidad, varias preguntas, lo cuál no es lo más adecuado para el formato del sitio y podría llegar a ser cerrada. Desde el título hay dos preguntas distintas, y luego en el cuerpo mencionas pruebas, sin decir cuales ni mostrar código. Te recomiendo leer [how-to-ask]. Un saludo.

Comment: Tu pregunta es interesante, me encantaría contestarla. Sin embargo, por el bien del sitio y mi reputación aquí, prefiero pedirte antes de eso, que separes tus preguntas en varias publicaciones y cuando lo hagas te daré una respuesta.

Comment: gracias por la ayuda y no se si el código que escribí sirva de algo

Comment: Hola, segun la documentacion: "Establece el bit en la posición dada", aqui esta su documentacion: [set_a(pos, valor=1)->Null](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.Mask.set_at)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo nunca usé máscaras en pygame, pero leyendo [la documentación](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html) podremos deducir que hace set_at.

#### ¿Que es una mascara?

Para empezar, una mascara parece ser un array de bits (0 ó 1), donde el bit 0 significa que el pixel correspondiente NO puede colisionar con algo, mientras el bit 1 representa que si puede.

Este es el funcionamiento basico de un booleano, 0 falso, 1 verdadero.

Al igual que con las imágenes, el origen de coordenadas está en la parte superior izquierda.

Esto significa que cada bit en la mascara indica si su correspondiente pixel colisiona o no.

Finalmente, un ejemplo de que representa una mascara:

```
0 1 1 0
1 0 0 1
0 1 1 0
```

En lo cual, si miras detenidamente, se forma una figura con los 1. Esa figura, es el area en la cual se considera que hay colisión. Los 0 rodeados por los 1 no forman parte de esta area.

#### ¿Qué hace set_at?

Entonces, la conclusión es que set_at establece el valor de ese bit. Teniendo en cuenta lo anterior, eso significa que set_at establece si ese pixel será o no capáz de colisionar.

#### Entonces, por que no notas ningún cambio.

Pues, esto se debe a que estás consultando la lista de puntos una vez. La lista de puntos que estás recibiendo no se actualiza, por lo que tecnicamente la lista no fue modificada por nadie y por eso al mostrarla en pantalla no hay cambios.

Comment: A pesar de que desconocías del tema me diste una respuesta muy buena, intentare otra vez con las mascaras

Comment: Gracias! Y suerte!